# How to find the input fps from camera in Android

Tags: android, opencv, camera, frame-rate

I am working with a Qualcomm Snapdragon processor with a periphery camera. The project I am working on needs to process the frames from the camera with OpenCV as quickly as possible. In order to verify that things are working, I would like to know the output fps achieved and also the input fps to see how many frames are being skipped. Is there a way to see how many frames per second the camera is providing to the processor? It should be able to work in the general case, for any input camera.

I've looked through the Camera2 API a bit, and found the parameter SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, but I am not quite sure how to access it. Also, I am using JavaCameraView, which seems to act as a bridge between Camera and OpenCV. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to modify JavaCameraView code to get this info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting frame rate calculated as below. In your onCameraFrame method you can measure the time taken between 2 consecutive frames.

```java
prevTime = time;
time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

Frame rate= (1000 / (time - prevTime))
```